# Need PHP substitution regex that excludes one case

Tags: php, regex, string-substitution

I need to substitute "::" (double colons) with a single forward slash "/" in a set of strings in all cases EXCEPT where the string ends in "]]". Example:

> SID:Common::Location ABE::Sub Location ABE

should go to

> SID:Common/Location ABE/Sub Location ABE

BUT

> [[Maps to SID::toto tata]]

should remain as is. I have tried various things, some involving a negative lookahead on the "]" character, but I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex for matching:

```
::(?!.*?\]\]$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jE9vD5/2)

`?!.*?\]\]$` is a negative lookahead which means fail the match if current line is ending with `]]`.

**Code:**

```
$re = '/::(?!.*?\\]\\]$)/';  
$result = preg_replace($re, '/', $input);
```

Comment: Thank you, anubhava. Great simple answer. This did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @sin: fixed the typo in the code. I try to keep things simple unless warranted by some specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look aheads

```
::(?!.*]]$)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jA7zU1/1)

```
preg_replace("/::(?!.*]]$)/", "/", "SID:Common::Location ABE::Sub Location ABE");
=> SID:Common/Location ABE/Sub Location ABE

preg_replace("/::(?!.*]]$)/", "/", "[[Maps to SID::toto tata]]");
=> [[Maps to SID::toto tata]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead

```
/^(?!\[\[)([^:]+)::/
```

and replace with `$1/`

Answer (score 0):

There is a N-Factorial type of latency if you try to do this in 1 regex.
The simplest way is to use 2 regex.

The first validates the string **doesn't** end in `]]`
(this is very quick):

```
\]\]$
```

Then just do a global replace with `/` using this:

```
(?<!:)::(?!:)
```